# get datetime from mysql with ajax returning NaN or undefined

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

So, here is the php/mysql code:

```
$postID = $_REQUEST['pIdPost'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,
    "SELECT 

comments.IdPost, comments.IdUser, 
comments.Comment AS Comment , users.UserImage , 
users.Username ,  DATE_FORMAT(comments.CommentDate, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS cDate

    FROM comments, users 

    WHERE 

    comments.IdPost = '$postID' 

    AND

    users.IdUser = comments.IdUser ")or die('Errant Query:'); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $output[]=$row;
        }

    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    print(json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    //print(json_encode($output));
    mysqli_close($con);
```

It fetches me a json array like this:

```
[{"IdPost":"2",
"IdUser":"5",
"Comment":"Me 3",
"UserImage":"images\/defaultUser.png",
"Username":"Mia",
"cDate":"16\/11\/2014 00:01:05"}]
```

All the ajax function is working perfectly except for the date that comes unidentified or if I parse it says NAN.

What could be wrong here? Can I Parse it to a string so that it comes in string format and this ends?

If so, how ?

Best regards,

Pihh

PS: The ajax as requested:

```
$.ajax({            
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://192.168.0.13/masonry/getSinglePost.php?pIdPost="+$(this).attr('data-item'),
            data:{},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var Comments = response;
                var $boxes;
                $.each(Comments, function (index, comment) {
                    $boxes = $(

                               '                 <span class="commentDescriptionTimeAgo">' +
/* comment.Date*/           '                     • ' + comment.cDate+
                               '                 </span>' +

                               );
                    $('#abv').append($boxes); //
```

Comment: Can you share with us your ajax function?

Comment: I think it's irrelevant but I'll post it ( the function is huge - it's to load a profile so I'll paste the part that matters ) - Other thing, if I change the date to other kind of value like postId it returns perfectly. 

Here it goes !

Comment: You have `TimeAgo`/`cDate` in your Ajax,  but I only see key of `CommentDate` in your returned json array, am I missing something.

Comment: in the meanwhile I've tried a lot of stuff and updated the code, the json strings match

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({            
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data:{},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var Comments = response;
            var $boxes;
            $.each(Comments, function (index, comment) {
                console.log(comment);
            });
        }
    });
```

This give me this in console:

```
2
5
Me 3 
images/defaultUser.png
Mia
16/11/2014 00:01:05
```

So, this code:

```
$.ajax({            
        type: "POST",
        url: "test",
        data:{},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var Comments = response;
            var $boxes;
            $.each(Comments, function (index, comment) {
                $boxes = '<span class="commentDescriptionTimeAgo">'+comment+'</span>';
                $('#abv').append($boxes); 
            });
        }
    });
```

output following:

> 25Me 3images/defaultUser.pngMia16/11/2014 00:01:05